# The default .bash_profile

Tags: macos, bash

I accidentally deleted the contents of `.bash_profile` in my new Macbook Air and want the default settings that comes with macOS Sierra.

Can anyone just copy/paste their `.bash_profile` that hasn't been edited?

Answer (score 6):

The default .bash_profile is empty, as the file doesn't exist in `/System/Library/User Template`. Anything you've deleted would be something you (or software you installed) has added, so it's not possible to say what that would be. Copying .bash_profile from elsewhere would depend on the environment being configured in such a similar way as where you're copying it from.